# ffmpeg: Convert 4K 10-bit file to DNxHR 444

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, transcoding

I have a 2160p29.97 AVI 10-bit RGB file recorded with a Blackmagic Intensity Pro 4K capture card.  I want to convert this file to DNxHR 444.

I used the following command to do so on Windows 10 with ffmpeg `3.3.2`.
ffmpeg -i "test.avi" -c:v dnxhd -profile:v dnxhr_444 "test_dnxhr444.mov"

I received this error:

> "[dnxhd @ 00000000026e6c60] dnxhr_444 or dnxhr_hqx profile is not
>   implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If
>   the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which
>   has not been implemented."

I tried running the command again with `dnxhr_sd` instead, which works.  So, does this mean that `dnxhr_444` does not work with ffmpeg at the moment?

Here is the full output for reference:

```
ffmpeg version N-83133-ge664730 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavcodec     57. 73.100 / 57. 73.100
  libavformat    57. 62.100 / 57. 62.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 69.100 /  6. 69.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
[avi @ 0000000000946500] non-interleaved AVI
[avi @ 0000000000946500] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from '20mintest.avi':
  Duration: 00:21:51.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1535764 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: r210 (r210 / 0x30313272), rgb48le(10 bpc), 3840x2160, 1582152 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s
[dnxhd @ 00000000026e6c60] dnxhr_444 or dnxhr_hqx profile is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (r210 (native) -> dnxhd (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> aac (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: Yes, not implemented at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [stated in this answer (includes an example)](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/20434/5349), as of ffmpeg 3.3.6, this is now supported.

The error no longer appears and you can convert to 444 without trouble.